# WDSL Connection time out (1006)

Tags: php, nusoap

I got a problems if me consume data with WDSL format use Nusoap Libary with php Programming. i got error like this : HTTP Error: Couldn't open socket connection to server http://x.x.x.x/aaa.php, Error (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

and this is my code

```
<?php

require 'nusoap/src/nusoap.php';

$wsdl="https://x.x.x.x/x.php?wsdl";
$username = "aa";
$password  = "bb";

$client =new nusoap_client($wsdl,true);
$client->setCredentials($username,$password);
$proxy = $client->getProxy();
$error  = $client->getError();

if ($error) 
{
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}

$result = $client->call("GetSOAPLPelaut", array("type" => "Main"));

if ($client->fault) 
{
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
} 
else 
{
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) 
    {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "<h2>Main</h2>";
        echo $result;
    }
}

echo "<h2>Request</h2>";
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>";
echo "<h2>Response</h2>";
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>";
```

maybe someone have solution about it ?

Comment: can you actually reach the WSDL? How long does it take to load? After which time does the timeout occur?

Comment: i was set default_socket_timeout = 3000

Comment: Can you reach https://x.x.x.x/x.php?wsdl with your browser?

Comment: i get an error Error (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. i try change localhost to 127.0.0.1 it's same

Comment: Silly question but are you sure you have the right endpoint and that the server there is running?

Comment: error still appears (10060)

Comment: how about it guys :)

Comment: please help me guys

Comment: maybe someone can help me ?